# Ошибка при попытке установить pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

Во время установки pyinstaller постоянно ошибка выскакивает. Все пробовал и ничего не помогает.

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2020.11)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\пользователь\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)
```

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: Требование уже выполнено: система считает что он установлен. Если не работает попробуйте удалить и установить его заново

Comment: попытался - безуспешно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у Вас директория python не прописана в path. Попробуйте запустить указав полный путь.
`PYTHON_DIR\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe`.

Можно вручную прописать директорию Scripts в PATH

Comment: я сейчас заглянул в скриптс и не нашел там пайинсталлера хоть уже 100 раз его установил. Несколько часов назад переустановил пито в диск C

Comment: А виртуальное окружение создавали? Если создать и установить в него?

Comment: я оказался лохом и неправильно указал путь в path спасибо за решение проблемы